# Xcode 8.2 & 8.1 crashes when enlarging any view in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

When I click on a view frame and drag to enlarge the view, the view is not getting enlarged . But instead the mouse waiting indicator would come for a second and then the whole xcode will crash.

This was happening after my code 8.2 update. So I tried installing xcode 8.1 and the issue is still there for one particular project. All other projects are working fine. There are no warnings or conflicts in the storyboard. I don't remember changing any settings as well.

Attaching the crash log: [CRASH_LOG](http://dpaste.com/2V1F13N)

Comment: Report a bug to Apple.

Comment: @GeneCode I found the issue. Check the answer. And sure it is a bug from apple.

Comment: Met the same issue and I download a xcode7.3.1 and it works. Seems this bug start from xcode8.1

Comment: @Xiangyu.Wu It is an xcode bug. I somehow managed to fix this . Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Fixed the issue:***

The issue  started after I added a  `ScrollView` to a `ViewController` and changed the `simulated size` of the `ViewController` to fit the scrollview content. I changed the `simulated size` to `freeform` and the issue started to appear. I changed it back to `fixed` and now everything is working normal.

> But I hope it shouldn't be happening and apple will fix this soon.